# How to enable Etag in NginX Sever for Php website?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, performance, nginx

I have tried all the solutions to add an etag to my website's static resources in Nginx. (for better caching performance I guess)

```
location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header  Cache-Control "public";
    try_files $uri @proxy;
    etag on;
}
```

The etag is not showing in header response or requests. Please help. Its an nginx+apache hybrid server.

Comment: Do you use nginx as a loadbalancer or webserver because you also tagged apache.. And what version of nginx do you use.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Nginx 1.14.0 and Apache 2.4.29, Nginx is used as reverse proxy server with apache in backend :)

Comment: "Nginx is used as reverse proxy server with apache in backend :) " in that case it makes more sense if you enable etags on the apache server(s)